# variables are not working in rand range statement in bubble sort program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I attempted to add a user input for the rand range statement and the total numbers in the list that it will sort through, I've tried everything I can to counter this but nothing seems to be working correctly.

```
import time
import random
def create_random_values():
    totalsortnum = (eval("Please enter the amount of numbers you wish to sort: "))

    rng1 = (eval("Please enter the maximum number range: "))
    randomList=[]
    for i in range (totalsortnum):
        randomList.append(random.randrange(1,rng1))
    return randomList, totalsortnum, rng1


def main():
    numList = create_random_values()
    print()
    print("Here is a random list of 20 numbers between 1 and 1000:")
    print(numList)

    pause = input("Hit <Enter> to start sorting")

    timeInitial = time.time()
    l = len(numList)
    for lastitem in range(l-1,0,-1):
        sorted = True
        for i in range(lastitem):
            if numList[i] > numList[i+1]:
                numList[i],numList[i+1] = numList[i+1],numList[i]
                sorted = False
            #print(numList)
            #pause = input("Hit <Enter> to start sorting")      
        if sorted == True:
            break
    timeFinal = time.time()
    print(numList)

    print("the selection sort of",len(numList),"items took:")
    print(timeFinal - timeInitial,"seconds.")
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval()` to try to get user input?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple problems with your code:

Inside of `create_random_values()` you're trying to use `eval()` for user input.
`eval()` is not the function you want, you want `input()`.

Inside of `main()` your `numList` variable is a 3-tuple, `(randomList, totalsortnum, rng1)`, I think you meant to reference just `randomList`.

This should work for you:

```
import time
import random
def create_random_values():
    totalsortnum = int(input("Please enter the amount of numbers you wish to sort: "))

    rng1 = int(input("Please enter the maximum number range: "))
    randomList=[]
    for i in range (totalsortnum):
        randomList.append(random.randrange(1,rng1))
    return randomList, totalsortnum, rng1

def main():
    numList, totalsortnum, rng1 = create_random_values()
    print()
    print("Here is a random list of {0} numbers between 1 and {1}:".format(totalsortnum, rng1))
    print(numList)

    pause = input("Hit <Enter> to start sorting")

    timeInitial = time.time()
    l = len(numList)
    for lastitem in range(l-1,0,-1):
        sorted = True
        for i in range(lastitem):
            if numList[i] > numList[i+1]:
                numList[i],numList[i+1] = numList[i+1],numList[i]
                sorted = False
            print(numList)
            #pause = input("Hit <Enter> to start sorting")      
        if sorted == True:
            break
    timeFinal = time.time()
    print(numList)

    print("the selection sort of",len(numList),"items took:")
    print(timeFinal - timeInitial,"seconds.")
```